# Foreach IN php not print first element

Tags: php, foreach

It is not available, but it is the most complete of the last two, the array [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtR8Q.png) and array [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwiyP.png), the array [0] does not show.

See below, can anyone help me?

Or any other way that can have the effect?

follow images to illustrate.

```
$horarios = $node->field_horarios['und'];


foreach( $horarios as $key => $value) {

    $diasemana = $value['day']; 
    $hora_inicio = $value['starthours'];
    $hora_termino = $value['endhours'];

    $hora_inicio_formatado = substr($hora_inicio,0,-2).':'. substr($hora_inicio,-2);
    $hora_termino_formatado = substr($hora_termino,0,-2).':'. substr($hora_termino,-2);



    $begin = new DateTime($hora_inicio_formatado);
    $end   = new DateTime($hora_termino_formatado);

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 min');

    $times    = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($times as $time) {

       echo $time->format('H:i'), '-', $time->add($interval)->format('H:i'), "\n";

    }

}
```

Image of arrays 
[image]

Image of code 
[image]

Comment: will you attach image of output you are getting instead of code image

Comment: Its because `starthours` is more than `endhours` in first element

Comment: We don't need an image of the code when you already posted the same thing as plain text.